# How can I loop array in data()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to iterate through an array in javascript inside vue.

I am using apex chart. I want to iterate over data[] according to the number of series(Y_Data_length).

I want to change code

```
data() {
      return {
        Y_Data_length: null,
        Options: {
          xaxis: {
            categories: [],
          },
        },
        Series_1: [{
          name: "",
          data: [],
        }],

        Series_2: [{
            name: "",
            data: [],
          },
          {
            name: "",
            data: [],
          }
        ],

        Series_3: [{
            name: "",
            data: [],
          },
          {
            name: "",
            data: [],
          },
          {
            name: "",
            data: [],
          }
        ],
      };
    },
```

to form it.

```
data() {
      return {
        Y_Data_length: null,
        Options: {
          xaxis: {
            categories: [],
          },
        },
        Series: [
          {name:"", data: []}
        ],
      };
    },
```

For reference, Y_Data_length is:

```
const A = this.chart[0].data
this.Y_Data_length = Object.keys(A).length
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to have understand correctly your problem but if you want to get the `data` array from a specific series, you can use a Vue "computed" to automatically get the correct series.data using `Y_Data_length` as an array index. Whenever `Y_Data_length` changes, then `this.currentSeriesData` will updates too.

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      Y_Data_length: null,
      Options: {
        xaxis: {
          categories: [],
        },
      },
      Series: [
        { name:"series1", data: [] },
        { name:"series2", data: [] },
        { name:"series3", data: [] },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    currentSeriesData() {
       const currentSeries = this.Series[this.Y_Data_length]
       if (currentSeries) {
         return currentSeries.data
       }
       return []
    }
  }
}
```